# SQL Server 2005 db Restore cannot complete

Tags: sql, database-restore

I have to restore a DB. DB and website are hosted on the same machine. I have turned the site off from IIS but restore still won’t complete because it says the DB is in use.   Do I have to stop all of the App Pools as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the database in [single user mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345598%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) That will close any connections to that database. Then you can proceed with the restore.

In summary, using Sql Server Management Studio:

1. In Object Explorer, connect to an instance of the SQL Server
   Database Engine, and then expand that instance.
2. Right-click the database to change, and then click Properties.
3. In the Database Properties dialog box, click the Options page.
4. From the Restrict Access option, select Single.
5. If other users are connected to the database, an Open Connections
   message will appear. To change the property and close all other
   connections, click Yes.

Also, using `exec sp_who2` you can see what spids are connected to that DB.